# How to describe narrated action?

Tags: poetry, homework, narration

Let's say we have a poem that has a first-person point of view and then goes like:

> I have eaten the cookies

Now, when I write about this poem and want to describe the action in the poem, would it be okay to write the following?

> The narrator has eaten some cookies

If not, what is the proper way to write about the narrated action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to the "narrator" or "the speaker" or (sometimes) "the poet" as having said the quoted material.

Comment: or maybe 'author'?